# Sorting algorithm nomenclature

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

What is the name of the following sorting algorithm?

```
 for i in range(1, len(a)):
    for j in range (0,i):
        if(a[j] > a[i]):
            a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i]
```

Comment: Looks like an [insertion sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) but I'm not sure, you can check it yourself: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Simple_sorts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a variant of insertion sort: before each iteration of the outer loop, a prefix of the list is sorted, and then each iteration of the outer loop inserts the following element into its correct position, growing the sorted prefix by 1. Ordinarily insertion sort would iterate downwards in the inner loop; this variant starts from the bottom, and hence cannot early-out of the inner loop once the new element is placed. Insertion sort ordinarily has best-case `O(n)`, but this variant is best-case `O(n^2)`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! This clarifies things, I used to do this when asked for bubble sort in exams!